# Prevent duplicate tagging in Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I must be really bad at this. I started to type "watches" for a tag and it appeared in the list because I used it before.

[image: Watches auto-complete]

Now when I click on it, I get two tags.

[image: Two tags for watches]

How can I get this working without adding the incomplete and the already existing tag ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an intended feature. You're supposed to be able to see "hey, I want that tag too" and click it to add both. The same thing happens when you push tab.

The functionality you really want is to push the `down` arrow key til you've selected the correct tag, then press `enter`.

Comment: Ah! So simple. Really don't know why that down arrow key escaped me.

Comment: :) well it is a little hard to "guess" when you're used to "tab", and then you're second option to "click" isn't the right one either...